# Addition of a stem, clamp and nuts

Tags: pstricks, pst-labo

I am starting to use the pst-labo package to make chemistry diagrams. I understood the principle, easily accessible, to trace them.
I would like to decorate the assemblies by adding a stem, nuts and clamps: how can I do it?

thanks for the help

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-labo}

\begin{document}

\psset{ unit =0.5cm}
\psgrid[subgriddiv=1,griddots=10,  gridlabels=5pt, gridwidth=0.5pt](0,0)(20,20)
\pstBallon[ refrigerantBoulles ,glassType=ballon]

\end{document}
```

The final diagram roughly corresponds to this:
[image: reflux]

Comment: Please post a small compilable example of what you got so far. This will help us come up with a solution that best fits your needs.

Comment: @JasperHabicht : i edit my post with an MWE

Comment: A sketch of the expected output would also be really useful here.

Comment: @leandriis :I added an example image

Comment: Looking through the documentation of `pst-labo` I don't think the package supports the elements that you are interested in - it seems to be that the diagrams from the package are more schematic, without the details of how the objects are kept in place physically.

Comment: @Marijn I thought that since the ```pst-labo``` package was based on ```pstricks```, it was possible to add elements outside the diagrams offered in the package

Comment: It is probably possible but I think it will be hard to get additional elements in the same style as the drawings in the package, and on the technical level it will be difficult to hook into the existing code. But maybe I'm too pessimistic and it can actually be done more easily than I think.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could draw your own, like in this example. You can then use the `\rput` command to shift it to the desired position.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-labo}

\newcommand{\pstClamp}{
    \colorlet{myfill}{brown!60}
    % potence
    \psframe[fillstyle=solid, fillcolor=myfill](-.5,-2.625)(-.25,13)
    \psframe[fillstyle=solid, fillcolor=myfill](-1,8)(1.75,7.75)
    \psframe[fillstyle=solid, fillcolor=myfill](-1,8.25)(-.75,7.5)
    \pscircle[fillstyle=solid, fillcolor=myfill](-.375,7.875){.2}
    \psframe[fillstyle=solid, fillcolor=myfill](1.5,8.15)(3,7.6)
    \psframe[fillstyle=solid, fillcolor=myfill](-1,4)(1.75,3.75)
    \psframe[fillstyle=solid, fillcolor=myfill](-1,4.25)(-.75,3.5)
    \pscircle[fillstyle=solid, fillcolor=myfill](-.375,3.875){.2}
    \psframe[fillstyle=solid, fillcolor=myfill](1.5,4.15)(3,3.6)
    % support elevateur
    \pspolygon[fillstyle=solid, fillcolor=myfill, linearc=.05](.25,-.25)(3.25,-1.25)(.25,-2.25)(1.25,-2.25)(4.25,-1.25)(1.25,-.25)
    \pspolygon[fillstyle=solid, fillcolor=myfill, linearc=.05](4.25,-.25)(1.25,-1.25)(4.25,-2.25)(3.25,-2.25)(.25,-1.25)(3.25,-.25)
    \psline(.25,-1.25)(4.5,-1.25)
    \psframe[fillstyle=solid, fillcolor=myfill](4.5,-1)(4.75,-1.5)
    \psframe[fillstyle=solid, fillcolor=myfill](0,0)(4.5,-.25)
    \psframe[fillstyle=solid, fillcolor=myfill](0,-2.25)(4.5,-2.5)
    % base
    \psframe[fillstyle=solid, fillcolor=myfill](-1,-2.5)(5,-2.75)
}

\begin{document}

\psset{unit=0.5cm}
\psgrid[subgriddiv=1, griddots=10, gridlabels=5pt, gridwidth=0.5pt](0,0)(20,20)
\pstBallon[refrigerantBoulles, glassType=ballon]

\pstClamp

\rput{0}(8,8){\pstClamp}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You can even flip it using `\rput{0}(0,0){\psset{xunit=-.5cm}\pstClamp}`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response